# How to use the equality operator correctly in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get all the flights of the `airline_name` and `destination` entred, but I get all flights of all airlines and all destinations not of the specified entries. What should I change in the code so it can work?

```
function get_flights_by_airline_destination(airline_name, destination, callback) {
      let request = require('request');
    
      let url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxx&flight_status=scheduled'
    
      request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error:', error);
          callback(err);
        } else {
          let vol = JSON.parse(body)
          result= []
          num = vol.pagination.limit
          for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            
            arrival = vol.data[i].arrival.timezone
            airline=vol.data[i].airline.name
            if ((destination == arrival)&&(airline_name == airline)) {
              one_flight = {number: vol.data[i].flight.number, date: vol.data[i].flight_date, departure: vol.data[i].departure.timezone, arrival: vol.data[i].arrival.timezone, from: vol.data[i].departure.airport, to: vol.data[i].arrival.airport,  airline: vol.data[i].airline.name}
              result.push(one_flight)
            }
          }
          callback(null, result)
        }
      });
     
    }
    function get_flights( req, res) {
       
       
      get_flights_by_airline_destination( 'air france','europe/rome' ,function( err, result) {
      
        if ( err) {
          console.log("error")
          }
        
         
        else {
          var links = []
          result.map( ( result) => {
            links.push(
              'from '+' '+result["departure"]+' '+ 'to'+' '+result["arrival"]+' '+'on'+' '+result["airline"],
                
              
            )
          })
            
          
          console.log(links)
          
    
        }
      })
    }
    get_flights()
```